# Continuity Issue in Java Calculator

Tags: java, switch-statement, calculator

I am new to Java, and I'm doing a calculator APP.

I'm trying to get my calculator to keep prompting the user for the correct answer (typing Y or N) after the else statement following 'Invalid Input'.
I want the program to continue with the calculations after the correct input is finally entered.

I have played around with an embedded `while` loop, but ended up with an infinite loop or a loop that terminates with no resolution. The code is below.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
class Calculate {
    public static void.main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println("Welcome To Calculator!");
            System.out.println("*************************************************************************");
            Scanner userinput = new Scanner(System.in);
            double num1, num2;
            String choice;
            boolean youDecide = true;
            while(youDecide == true) {
                System.out.println("Please enter a number: ");
                num1 = userinput.nextDouble();
                System.out.println("Please enter an available operator (+, -, *, /): ");
                char operator = userinput.next().charAt(0);
                System.out.println("Please enter another number: ");
                num2 = userinput.nextDouble();
                double output;      
                switch(operator) 
                {
                case '+':
                    output = num1 + num2;
                    break;
                
                case '-':
                    output = num1 - num2;
                    break;
                
                case '*':
                    output = num1 * num2;
                    break;
                
                case '/':
                    output = num1 / num2;
                        if(num2 == 0)
                            System.out.println("Math error! A number cannot be divided by zero.");
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Invalid input. Please enter an available operator, i.e (+, -, *, /): ");
                    return;
                }
                System.out.println("*************************************************************************");
                System.out.println("The answer is: " + "\n" + output);
                System.out.println("*************************************************************************");
                System.out.println("Would you like to calculate again?");
                System.out.println("Please enter Y for yes, or N for no");
                choice = userinput.next();
            
                if(choice.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {
                    System.out.println("Okay. Let's continue!");
                    System.out.println("*************************************************************************");
                    youDecide = true;
                }
                else if(choice.equalsIgnoreCase("N")) {
                    System.out.println("*************************************************************************");
                    System.out.println("Okay. Thanks for using Calculator. Goodbye!");
                    System.exit(0);
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("Invalid input. Please try again...");   
                    System.out.println("*************************************************************************");
                    youDecide = false;
                }
        }
    
    }

}
```

Comment: `public static void.main()` how did that compile?  Always copy/paste code, never retype it in a StackOverflow question.

Comment: Why did you set `youDecide = false` in the Invalid Input section?  That's telling the loop to end, and it belongs in the `'N'` choice instead of `System.exit(0)`.

Comment: Jim, I posted this from my phone, so I had to edit the text to be able to post the code within the question. I did paste the code,  but the site complained indentions, so this was the result.

Comment: Also, the System.exit(0) seems to be the only way to get the program to terminate once the user is prompted for a decision  to continue and enters 'N'. I was playing around with an embedded while loop for the else statement in which, after the user finally enters a correct input, then the main loop will continue. This is the part where I ran into problems as I ended up with either an infinite embedded loop or an early terminating one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding the edits suggested by J.F. and Javaman along with some research, I was able to solve the problem by adding the following lines to my code:

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;


class Calculator {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Welcome To Calculator!");
        System.out.println("*************************************************************************");
        Scanner userinput = new Scanner(System.in);
        char operator;
        double num1, num2;
        String choice;
        while(true) {
            System.out.println("Please enter a number: ");
            num1 = userinput.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Please enter an available operator (+, -, *, /): ");
            while(true) {
                operator = userinput.next().charAt(0);  
                if(operator == '+' || operator == '-' || operator == '*' || operator == '/') {
                    break;
                }else {
                    System.out.println("Invalid input. Please enter an available operator, i.e (+, -, *, /): ");
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Please enter another number: ");
            num2 = userinput.nextDouble();
            double output;
    
            switch(operator) {
            case '+':
                output = num1 + num2;
                break;      
            case '-':
                output = num1 - num2;
                break;  
            case '*':
                output = num1 * num2;
                break;      
            case '/':
                output = num1 / num2;
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Invalid input. Please enter an available operator, i.e (+, -, *, /): ");
                continue;
            }
            System.out.println("*************************************************************************");                
            if(num2 == 0) {
                System.out.println("Math error! A number cannot be divided by zero.");
            }else {
                System.out.println("The answer is: " + "\n" + output);
            } 
            System.out.println("*************************************************************************");
            System.out.println("Would you like to calculate again?");
            System.out.println("Please enter Y for yes, or N for no");
            choice = userinput.next();
     
            if(choice.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {
                System.out.println("Okay. Let's continue!");
                System.out.println("*************************************************************************");
            }else if(choice.equalsIgnoreCase("N")) {
                System.out.println("*************************************************************************");
                System.out.println("Okay. Thanks for using Calculator. Goodbye!");
                System.exit(0);
            }else {
                System.out.println("Invalid input. Please try again...");   
                System.out.println("*************************************************************************");        
                **while (!("Y").equalsIgnoreCase(choice) && !("N").equalsIgnoreCase(choice)) {
                    System.out.println("Invalid input. Please try again...");   
                    System.out.println("*************************************************************************");        
                    System.out.println("Please enter Y for yes, or N for no");
                    choice = userinput.next();
                    if(choice.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {
                        System.out.println("Okay. Let's continue!");
                        System.out.println("*************************************************************************");
                    }else if(choice.equalsIgnoreCase("N")) {
                        System.out.println("*************************************************************************");
                        System.out.println("Okay. Thanks for using Calculator. Goodbye!");
                        System.exit(0);**
                    }
                }
            }
        }
   }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a `while` loop to ensure the value is correct.

Due the logic into your code you need to do when the user type the char, otherwise you have to change many lines of code, or ask for all values again.

I think for a begginer the easiest way is using this loop:

```java
char operator;
while(true) {
    operator = userinput.next().charAt(0);
    if(operator=='+' || operator == '-' || operator == '*' || operator == '/') {
        break;
    }else {
        System.out.println("Please enter a valid operator: ");
    }
}
```

Exists many ways more elegant to do this. But I think for a begginer is the easiest way to understand and implement the code.

This loop is only to ensure the user type a valid character. While the character is not one of them, the loop will be iterating.

You have to place this code just below this line where you ask for a valid operator.

Answer (score 1):

I've made some changes and comments to your code

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Calculator {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Welcome To Calculator!");
        System.out.println("*************************************************************************");
        Scanner userinput = new Scanner(System.in);
        double num1, num2;
        String choice;

        //the "youDecide" variable is not needed at all
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Please enter a number: ");
            num1 = userinput.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Please enter an available operator (+, -, *, /): ");
            char operator = userinput.next().charAt(0);
            System.out.println("Please enter another number: ");
            num2 = userinput.nextDouble();
            double output;
            switch (operator) {
            case '+':
                output = num1 + num2;
                break;

            case '-':
                output = num1 - num2;
                break;

            case '*':
                output = num1 * num2;
                break;

            case '/':
                output = num1 / num2;
                if (num2 == 0) {
                    System.out.println("Math error! A number cannot be divided by zero.");
                }
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Invalid input. Please enter an available operator, i.e (+, -, *, /): ");
                continue; //changed from "return" you don't want to exit, just to skip to the next execution of the loop
            }
            System.out.println("*************************************************************************");
            System.out.println("The answer is: " + "\n" + output);
            System.out.println("*************************************************************************");
            System.out.println("Would you like to calculate again?");
            System.out.println("Please enter Y for yes, or N for no");
            choice = userinput.next();

            if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {
                System.out.println("Okay. Let's continue!");
                System.out.println("*************************************************************************");
            } else if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("N")) {
                System.out.println("*************************************************************************");
                System.out.println("Okay. Thanks for using Calculator. Goodbye!");
                System.exit(0);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Invalid input. Please try again...");
                System.out.println("*************************************************************************");
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Javaman. After applying your edits, everything still works. Now how would I go about getting the program to keep prompting the user for a correct input until one is finally entered, then returning to the main loop? I am referring to this part of the code:                                                                                   } else {
                System.out.println("Invalid input. Please try again...");
                System.out.println("*************************************************************************");
            }
        }

    }
}